# Write access to repository not granted

Tags: git, repository, branch

I connected to the git-repository
with a command:

`git clone https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<organizationname>/<repo>.git`

And now when I try to do the command:

`git push -u origin <branch-name>`

to upload the branch to publish

This is the error I get:

```
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<organization-name>/<repo>/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I didn't create the repository, so I don't have access to the settings, etc.

How can it be fixed anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the repository owner can grant you to push.

Else you should fork the repo, work on a new branch, then issue a merge request.

Comment: Is it possible to create a fork from a private repository?

Comment: You stated that you cloned that repo, so you can.

Comment: With what command?From the github website I can't do it.

Comment: @maia google is your friend